# Display logs in a specific order on Kibana visualization

Tags: kibana-7

I try visualize some logs of a scheduler by an histogram on Kibana
but see the logs not in the same order as I expected. Can I define the order or cause it been shown in the accurate order the logs are coming?

I filtered the logs by a query like this:

```
{
  "bool": {
    "should": [
      {
        "term": {
          "jsonPayload.msg.keyword": "starting Scheduler"
        }
      },
      {
        "term": {
          "jsonPayload.msg.keyword": "moving file to a new directory"
        }
      },
      {
        "term": {
          "jsonPayload.msg.keyword": "moving file failed"
        }
      },
      {
        "term": {
          "jsonPayload.msg.keyword": "Finish Scheduler"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and added a bucket of Date Histogram and sub bucket of the same term I filtered by: `jsonPayload.msg.keyword` for visualize each 15 minutes the count for each type of log
like you can see below:
[image]
and got something like that:
[image]
as the light-blue line describe the log `"moving file to a new directory"` and the red `"moving file failed"` what write and also take place in this order but actually the red line is shown before the light-blue

Answer (score 1):

As Github Kibana page explains, it is a known and open issue.

[Issue 86184](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/86184)

[Issue 17532](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/17532)